# [JavaScript]Is there a way to use Cloudinary without terminal

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

my development environment(chat bot app) doesnt offer terminal.(uses Rhino)
but what I can do is putting module(.js) files in it.

Would there be a way to use Cloudinary upload and etc codes?
It would be nice if there is a .js format of Cloudinary module.

Comment: There is https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudinary

Answer (score 0):

I'm Danny and I work on Cloudinary's Developer Support team.

We've got a [Node SDK](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration), as well as a [jQuery](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_integration) one and a [vanilla Javascript](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/javascript_quick_start) one too. If you're just looking to allow users to upload content via your site, [the upload widget](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget) may be a better solution for you.

Would you mind posting a little about your use case? If you let us know the specific problem you're trying to solve, we should be able to help. Feel free to reply here, or if you're providing specific details about your account, you may prefer to raise a ticket via [our support center](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).

Looking forward to hearing back from you.